# simple_format in observer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, helper, text-formatting, observers

I've ran into another problem while outsourcing some notification logic to observers.

Is it possible to use simple_format inside of an observer?

I need it to transform text from database and strings from I18n.t into nice looking emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.
Just include the TextHelper-Module at the start of the file to use helpers like simple_format:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
class SystemmailerObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  [...]
end
```